# Executing exe file with option from Powershell

Tags: powershell

How to run the below command in PowerShell. The below command will prompt for a password and user needs to enter it.  I want to automate it.

```
mxexport [ -f <zip file name> ]
```

I tried saving password in a file and run the below script in PowerShell:

```
$password = get-content C:\cred.txt | convertto-securestring
$pass=[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password))
& 'C:\Program Files\XX\XX\bin\mxexport.exe' -f file.zip, -p $pass
```

But I am getting the below Error:

```
mxexport.exe'
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error while getting password from User.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: Do you get meaningful values for `$password` and `$pass`? Are you sure are calling `mxexport` with the correct value?  Have you tried calling `mxexport` with a hard-coded value for `$pass`?

Comment: I just found out, mxexport accepts only one option called -f filename.  But It is prompting for a password when I press enter after running a command mxexport.exe -f filename.  How you to get the password from a file and execute the command without prompting fora password to enter.

Answer (score 2):

You are using single quotes, therefore the `$pass` variable doesn't get resolved. You also don't need to wrap the arguments within quotes, just use:

```
& "C:\Program Files\XX\XX\bin\mxexport.exe" -p $pass
```

---

**Edit to your comment**

Try to pass the parameters using splatting:

```
$arguments = @("-f file.zip", "-p $pass")
& "C:\Program Files\XX\XX\bin\mxexport.exe" @arguments
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. mxexport has only one option. i.e Filename. But It is asking for a Password. Below is the error I am getting. 

`CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error while getting password from User.:String)`

Comment: Sorry for the confusuion. I just edited my question. mxexport.exe has only one option that will accept filename, If I give password as another parameter, It is not accepting. But whenever we give enter after mxexport.exe, Its prompting for a password. So I need my script to get the password from file instead of user input.

Comment: Ensure you `$pass` contains the password. Then try to pass the parameters using splatting (see me edit)

Comment: nope.Not working. I cant pass the password as parameter.

Comment: Okay, my last attempt would be to pass the parameter plain (without loading it from the file).

Comment: I think you are not getting it. mxexport has only one option. i.e filename. We cant pass anything other than filename.

Comment: based on this document http://h18013.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/hpsim/info-library51/mxexport.1m.html , mxexport *does* support passing a password. If not, your question would be about how to pass a value to a form with PowerShell and it would lack a lot of information to solve it.